# DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter method freeze UI in a particular call

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm calling the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` method after I modify a property of an object (I'm firing it with KVO). I'm only showing a confirm view for a second and then run a block which do another things on the UI (pops a viewcontroller). The problem is that when i call this from a `UICollectionViewCell` works fine, but when i call this method from another particular `UICollectionViewCell` in my app, it freezes up. The method is implemented in a extension of `UIView`.

```
public func showConfirmViewWith(title: String!, frame: CGRect? = screenBounds, afterAction: (() -> Void)?) {

    let confirm = ConfirmationView(frame: frame!, title: title)

    self.addSubview(confirm)

    confirm.checkBox?.setCheckState(.checked, animated: true)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1) ) {

        if afterAction != nil  {
            afterAction!()
        }
       confirm.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

When it freezes the code inside the Dispatch never gets called, I have a breakpoint inside, but never gets to that point.

**UDPATE** 
Here's the stack trace when i pause the execution:

[First time I paused the execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZnM9.png)

Comment: When your app freezes, click on the pause button in the debugger and look at the stacktrace to see what your app is stuck on.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the stack trace when I pause the execution. But if i press play and pause again, not always its in the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this tricky bug. First thing, there wasn't any problem with the DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter call. The app was going into a loop and wasn't any signs that was lock. I ran the profiler and saw that the layout of some constraints was being called over and over. I have a tableView inside the collectionViewCell, and an animation when finish the call to asyncAfter. The problem was that the overriden method layoutSubviews has a tableView.reloadData() inside, so everytime i was trying to exit after the async call with an animation, the layoutsubviews was being called and the reloadData() triggered over and over again. I'm not sure why that reloadData was there, but seems to be working fine now.